# Is this expression $(a \land b) \land c$ the same as $a \land b \land c$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to create a Conjunctive Normal Form, which is from $(a \land b) \leftrightarrow c$.

Now the issue is that I'm not sure whether $(a \land b) \land c$ is the same as saying $a \land b \land c$.

Especially when I will be applying De Morgan's Laws, so in that case whether $\neg(a \land b) \land \neg c$ is the same as $\neg a \land \neg b \land \neg c$.

Thanks.

Comment: Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) : the conjuction has the associative property as one would expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(A\land B)\land C=A\land(B\land C)=A\land B\land C.$$

But

$$\lnot(A\land B)\land \lnot C\ne \lnot A\land \lnot B\land\lnot C.$$

Answer (score 2):

I clarify a bit better : because of the conjuction is a binary operator, then you have to choose which of the operations you want to do first. So , suppose $A\land B\land C$ stays for $(A\land B)\land C$. But you can prove $((A\land B)\land C) \iff (A\land (B\land C))$ because the conjuction is associative. So :

$$((A\land B)\land C) \iff (A\land (B\land C)) \iff (A\land B\land C)$$

Comment: I can't see the purpose of your first identity. Because your second identity says that the left member of the $\lor$ is true, and the right member can take any value.

Comment: You're right, I intended this, now it should be good

Answer (score 2):

The symbol $\land$ is a binary operation. It takes **two** well-formed formulae, $\varphi$ and $\psi$, and produces a third, $\varphi \land\psi$. It is *associative*, in the sense that, for any three well-formed formulae, $\theta$, $\varphi$, and $\psi$, we have

$$\theta\land(\varphi \land \psi)\equiv (\theta\land\varphi)\land\psi.\tag{$A$}$$

(Can you prove $(A)$?)

> A proof tree, generated [here](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(A%E2%88%A7(B%E2%88%A7C))%E2%86%94((A%E2%88%A7B)%E2%88%A7C)), is [image]

Now it's just a matter of the [generalised associativity law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#); the point being:

$$A\land B\land C$$

means, technically, *both* $(A\land B)\land C$ and $A\land(B\land C)$, since they are equivalent; so *the parentheses are still there* - one just omits them for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCuYr.png]

These are the same laws in logic, just replace the notations $\cup=\lor$ and $\cap=\land$ and $\bar X=\lnot x$

So these equalities are true in particular

$\overline{(A\land B)}\land \bar C=(\bar A\lor \bar B)\land \bar C=(\bar A\land\bar C)\lor(\bar B\land \bar C)=\overline{(A\lor C)}\lor\overline{(B\lor C)}$